# How to upload .net core build artifacts into JFrog Artifactory Cloud

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-devops, jfrog-cli

I have configured build pipeline for .net core application in Azure DevOps. In that I have added the **Artifactory Generic Upload** build task to upload build artifacts into JFrog Artifactory instead of keeping in Azure DevOps Server.

In the Artifactory Generic Upload task, I am using this file spec configuration.

```
{
  "files": [
    {
      "pattern": "*.zip",
      "target": "generic-local" // This is my generic repository name in JFrog Artifactory Cloud
    }
  ]
}
```

Whenever I run the build, then I am getting the below error.

```
> [Error] No errors, but also no files affected (fail-no-op flag).

{

  "status": "success",

  "totals": {

    "success": 0,

    "failure": 0

  }

}

##[debug]task result: Failed

##[error]Error: Command failed: C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\jfrog\1.38.4\x64\jfrog.exe rt u --url="https://xxxxx.jfrog.io/artifactory" --user=*** --password=*** --fail-no-op=true --dry-run=false --insecure-tls=false --threads=3 --retries=3 --symlinks=false
```

So, can anyone suggest me how to upload .net core build artifacts into JFrog Artifactory Cloud.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have changed the File Spec like this below:

```
{
  "files": [
    {
      "pattern": "$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/*.zip",
      "target": "generic-local/generic-local/drop/" // Format: "Repository_Name/Repository_Path/Folder_Name/"
    }
  ]
}
```

With this File Spec configuration, I am able to upload .NET Core build artifacts into JFrog Artifactory.

Reference documentation : https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory#CLIforJFrogArtifactory-UploadingFiles